# Sql 2 values in to one

Tags: sql-server

I have a query below:

```
SELECT distinct CBP.Liability 
FROM Markets M 
INNER JOIN BetTransaction B ON B.MarketId = M.MarketId AND BetSize > 0
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT ISNULL (min(Liable),0) AS Liability FROM ClientBetPosition WHERE MarketId = M.MarketId AND ClientId = 349
) AS [CBP]
WHERE M.MarketId NOT IN (SELECT MarketId FROM Transactions WHERE MarketID IS NOT NULL)
AND B.ClientId = 349
```

Which is showing me result of 1 column and 2 rows,
i need to add them in to one row

Comment: please provide expected result and actual result

Comment: Please sometime use google.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: sorry to bother you all it is soo simple i just need to edit first line 

SELECT sum (distinct CBP.Liability  )